# CoreData, my entity is empty.. why?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, entity

could you help me and tell me why my entity is empty ?

i'm populating my entity with my JSON, my entity's attributes has the same name as in my JSON

this is my code to populate my entity :

```
  NSManagedObjectContext *cxt = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newBoxes = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Boxes" inManagedObjectContext:cxt];
    NSDictionary *parsedFeed = [[newBoxes entity] attributesByName];
    for (NSString *key in parsedFeed) {
        id value = [parsedFeed objectForKey:key];
        // Don't assign NSNull, it will break assignments to NSString, etc.
        if (value && [value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
            value = nil;

        @try {
            [Boxes setValue:value forKey:key];
        } @catch (NSException *exception) {
            // Exception means such attribute is not defined in the class or some other error.
        }
    }

    NSError *err;
    if (![cxt save:&err]) {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }



NSLog(@"ENTITY  %@", newBoxes);
```

this is the result of my NSLOG :

```
2012-04-30 11:16:23.352 Wonder[9987:fb03] ENTITY  <Boxes: 0x6d87330> (entity: Boxes; id: 0x6d8b010 <x-coredata://EFDCC0BA-644D-42AC-8DE8-452F02B7C680/Boxes/p26> ; data: {
    codeArticle = nil;
    descriptionBox = nil;
    dlu = 0;
    kindBox = nil;
    nameBox = nil;
    nbActivities = 0;
    note = 0;
    priceBox = 0;
    texteMarketing = nil;
    typeBox = nil;
})
```

this is my JSON :

```
{
    "totalBox":{
        "boxes":[
        {
         "codeArticle": "WPCDE01C412L",
         "nameBox": "boxName",
         "texteMarketing": "boxTextMarketing",
         "descriptionBox" : "boxDescritpion",
         "nbActivities": 1650,
         "kindBox": "boxKind",
         "typeBox": "boxType",
         "priceBox": 20,
         "dlu": 2014,
         "note": 3
        },
        {
         "codeArticle": "BOOYAKA!!",
         "nameBox": "boxNameName",
         "texteMarketing": "boxTextMarketing",
         "descriptionBox" : "boxDescritpion",
         "nbActivities": 1650,
         "kindBox": "boxKind",
         "typeBox": "boxType",
         "priceBox": 39,
         "dlu": 2014,
         "note": 3
         }
        ]
            }
}
```

this is my entity :

[image]

EDIT : i give my JSON, so i should "tell" my coredata what it should read to populate my entity, right ?

```
dataToDisplay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//récupération du chemin vers le fichier contenant le JSON
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"JSON" ofType:@"txt"];

//création d'un string avec le contenu du JSON
NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];   

//Parsage du JSON à l'aide du framework importé
NSDictionary *json    = [myJSON JSONValue];

//récupération  du total des Boxes
NSDictionary *resultats    = [json objectForKey:@"totalBox"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code above you are trying to set values on a non object.

```
[Boxes setValue:value forKey:key];
```

Should be

```
[newBoxes setValue:value forKey:key];
```

I would recommend that you take a look at http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/ and this super useful article on JSON and CoreData http://www.cimgf.com/2012/01/11/handling-incoming-json-redux/

Cheers
mbogh

Comment: thanks man or your answer, you are right i was making a mistake but it still doesnt populate my entity ( with my JSON ) but finally i was thinking about "i'm stupid i'm not giving my JSON" look my edit, pls :)

Comment: Also seems you don't access the JSON content at all, NSDictionary *parsedFeed = [[newBoxes entity] attributesByName];. This just fetches all the keys from the NSManagedObject enity...

Comment: is that populate my Coredata ? with my json ? 
i'm seriously lost, i need help :/ i just want to populate my coredata with my json, then afterwards i will do some request as : i need all of the codeArticle which has a price > 25€.

[Boxes setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:json];

Answer (score 2):

> i'm populating my entity with my JSON, my entity's attributes has the same name as in my JSON

Not in any of the code you have posted in the question.

This line:

```
NSManagedObject *newBoxes = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Boxes" inManagedObjectContext:cxt];
```

Creates a new **empty** managed object.  There's no data.

This code:

```
NSDictionary *parsedFeed = [[newBoxes entity] attributesByName];
```

Gets a dictionary of all the attribute names of the managed object and the attribute descriptions.  This is part of the model.  I don't know why you are bothering to access it at all.

This code

```
for (NSString *key in parsedFeed) {
    id value = [parsedFeed objectForKey:key];
    // Don't assign NSNull, it will break assignments to NSString, etc.
    if (value && [value isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        value = nil;

    @try {
        [Boxes setValue:value forKey:key];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        // Exception means such attribute is not defined in the class or some other error.
    }
}
```

is quite bizarre.  You access the attribute description (which tells Core Data things like is the attribute a string, number etc) and then set a key in `Boxes` to that value.  I'm guessing `Boxes` is the subclass of `NSManagedObject` you have created to model a box.  If you hadn't decided to catch the exception, I'm guessing that your code would crash here with "does not respond to selector".

Basically, nothing you do in your code makes any sense.  What you need to do is get an NSDictionary of the JSON, see [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and use that where you are currently using parsedFeed.  Then your code will more or less work (replacing `Boxes` with `newBoxes`.  However, I will suggest a couple of modifications:

```
NSDictionary *parsedFeed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWith....]; // can use an NSData or a stream
for (NSString *key in parsedFeed) {
    id value = [parsedFeed objectForKey:key];
    // Don't assign NSNull, it will break assignments to NSString, etc.
    if ([value isEqual:[NSNull null]]) // nil is already handled OK
        value = nil;

    if ([legalKeys containsObject: key]) // see comment below
    {
        [newBoxes setValue: value forKey: key];
    } 
    else
    {
        // report bad data
    }       
}
```

`legalKeys` is a set you have created in your source code that says which keys can legally be set from the JSON, which presumably comes from outside.  This is a form of validation and prevents keys that should not be set from being set by bad data. For instance, `NSObject` has a property called `scriptingProperties`.  You probably don't want incoming JSON to set that.